# How to find all instances of an interface in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to make Eclipse show all instances of an interface?

That is: If I have an interface named `IMyInterface`, I want Eclipse to show me all objects that are of type `IMyInterface` in my workspace. I want to learn all instances of an interface, e.g. all lines that start with `IMyInterface iMyInterfaceInstance = ...`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to press <kbd>F4</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>) when the cursor is on the interface name. This will open the "Type Hierarchy" tab where you'll be able to see all types of `IMyInterface`.

If you need to see all references of the interface inside your workspace, you can press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+G</kbd> when the cursor in on the interface name.